# Integration using Gauss-Laguerre quadrature

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, quadrature

I need to solve integral using Gauss-Lagerre'e quadrature: 
$\int_0^\infty e^{-10x}(5x^3-\pi)$ on interval [0, $\infty$).

I am not really familiar with this kind of methods, but I need to solve it this way. This is how I am doing that, but I think everything is going bad.

I know that on the beginning I need to determinate the orthogonal `n` degree, where my `n = 3`:

$L_0(x)=1$

$L_1(x)=x-1$

$L_2(x)=x^2-4x+0$

$L_3(x)=x^3-9x^2+18x-6$

The weight function $p(x)$ that ensures convergence of integrals is $e^{-x}$.

Now I set the $A_k$ coefficient(whatever that means) using the expression below:

$A_k = \frac{((N+1)!)}{L_{N+1}(x_k)L_{N+2}(x_k)}$ ,

where $x_k$ are the real zeros of the polynomial.

At the end I have the integration expression:

$\int_0^\infty e^{-x}f(x)dx = \sum_{k=0}^N A_kf(x_k)$

So lets get started.

1)Calculations of the $A_k$.

$A_0 = \frac{((0+1)!)}{-1*(-1)} = \frac{1}{1} = 1$ //It's wrong because there is not real zero of $L_0(x)=1$ ?

$A_1 = \frac{2!}{1} = 2$

$A_2 = \frac{3!}{4*0} = \frac{6}{0} $ NEVER divide by 0!!!

etc.

What I am doing wrong? How to calculate integrals using given method?

Comment: From where do you have the formula for the $A_k?$ 
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Laguerre_quadrature)
and [Mathworld (14)](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Laguerre-GaussQuadrature.html) give

$$A_i = \frac {x_i} {(n+1)^2[L_{n+1}(x_i)]^2}$$
The formula 25.4.45 in [Abramowitz/Stegun](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_890.htm) is another equivalent.

Comment: @gammatester From a book "Fortuna Macukow Numerical Methods"

Comment: @gammatester The $[L_{n+1}(x_i)]^2$ means that the result of the orthogonal polynomial is raised to power of 2?

Comment: I've made new calculations. 
$A_0=\frac{-1}{(0+1)^2(-x+1)^2} = \frac{-1}{(0^2+2*0*1+1^2)(-x^2+2*(-x)*1+1^2)} = \frac{-1}{(0+0+1)(x-2x+1)} = \frac{-1}{x-2x+1} = \frac{-1}{-1-2*(-1)+1} = \frac{-1}{2}$

Comment: The $x_i$ are the **roots** of $L_n$, I do not see any of them, look e.g. here for the abscisssas and weights: http://www.efunda.com/math/num_integration/findgausslaguerre.cfm

Comment: So I can calculate the $\sum_{k=0}^N A_kf(x_k)$ if i will take the roots  from the site to which you have given the link?

Comment: I'll eventually write a more complete answer, but two good reading to begin with: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Laguerre_quadrature https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_quadrature Note that the Gauss-Laguerre method is suited to integrand $e^{-x}f(x)$ where $f$ is smooth enough. Here you can do a change of variable to get the correct form. This method is designed to be exact for polynomial $f$ of degree up to $2n$. You will be able to compute your integral even with a low $n$ at the link gammatester provided in his anwser (https://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/1281601254).

Comment: There are plenty of material on the web on Gaussian quadrature, Google is your friend! Usually, to integrate $\int_a^b w(x)f(x)dx$, you build an orthogonal family of polynomials based on the scalar product $(f,g)=\int_a^b w(x)f(x)g(x) dx$. Their roots give the abscissas, and a simple formula gives the weights.

Comment: @gammatester, I apologise, I understand I was a bit rude. I still believe your question should be amended, not deleted. An important point: Newton-Cotes usually gives much worse results than Gaussian quadrature, especially when it's designed to fit the integrand, as is the case here. In some way, Gaussian quadrature is optimal: for instance, Gauss-Legendre gives the abscissas such that the method is exact on polynomial up to degree $2n-1$, whil NC would be exact only up to degree $n$. This $2n-1$ is the maximum possible with $n$ points.